# Get the values of id2

Tags: excel, vba, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <id xmlns="id.services/">
         <ids1>
            <response xmlns="">
               <ids xmlns="ids">
                  <Id-info xmlns="" id0="123" id1="0" id2="2345" />
                  <Id-info xmlns="" id0="456" id1="1" id2="6789" />
               </ids>
            </response>
         </ids1>
      </id>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How can I get the values of id2 using vba excel?. This is the code that I have tried

```
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
xmlDoc.Load ("C:test.xml")

Dim id As String
id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ids/Id-info").Attributes.getNamedItem("id2").Text
```

Comment: Tirath... can you update your post to be a bit more descriptive, while also utilizing the code snippit appropriately to capture your spacing, indents, etc.?

Comment: Dim id As String id - Looks wrong. IIRC You define a variable to be one type.

Comment: I have edited your post again. Please do not remove the code

Comment: Your code works fine however, when I did a direct copy and paste from here it wouldn't except the xml. I think you may have an issue with your source. Put it in a parser and make sure it passes.

Answer (score 3):

You will only access one value with that.

Try

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, items As Object, node As IXMLDOMElement
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False
        If Not .Load("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml") Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If
    End With
    Set items = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Id-info")
    If Not items Is Nothing Then
        For Each node In items
            Debug.Print node.getAttribute("id2")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks QHarr!How can i get both id2 values using function?

Comment: You can get both ids above using that sub.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks QHarr!    I got it